# How to get first zeroes and add to the power?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a variable in visual basic 2010, with the value of 0,000041 and how to make this value like this? 4.1E-5

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the values are the same but if you want to print it or get a string out of it you can use the `"E"` or `"e"` format string:

```
(0.000041).ToString("E");
```

which should give you something like `"4,100000E-005"`

you can even specify how many significant digits you like with a number after:

```
(0.000041).ToString("e1");
```

gives you `"4,1e-005"`

you can find this and much more in the [MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)